# How to transform data and make every possible dyadic comparison between data?

Tags: r

I'm having some difficulty in transforming some data for a future analysis.

What I have:

My rows are individual participants who give their perceptions of others' relative rank. These ranking values are the data (range 0 - 1) and each column is a particular individual (target) who has received a given ranking by all the participants in the rows. I.e., there are 28 columns presenting 28 individuals (targets) who received rankings from the participants (raters).

What I would like:

For each row (rater) I want to make every possible dyadic comparison between the targets they rated (the 28 column vars) and a variable that codes which target received the higher ranking from the rater for each of these comparisons.

I think I need two new variables who that track the targets' ID numbers being compared (person_1 and person_2, for example) and somehow their value, and then make the comparison and print the target's ID with the higher ranking in a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no sample data, I did the following:

```
set.seed(123)
raters <- paste0('rater', 1:28)
targets <- paste0('target', 1:28)
dat <- matrix(runif(28 * 28), ncol = 28, dimnames = list(raters, targets))
```

You can create 2-combinations of the targets with the `combn` function:

```
combos <- combn(targets, 2, simplify=FALSE)
```

Now you can create a list of matrices, each with 2 columns chosen from the combos:

```
dyads <- lapply(combos, function(x) dat[,x])
```

The column names of each matrix in dyads is the target_x, target_y combination you're interested, so to return the name of the target with the higher rating you could do this:

higher_rating <- lapply(dyads, function(y) 
                               colnames(y)[apply(y, 1, function(x) which.max(x))])

To get a list of higher ratings along with the compared targets, you bash together the compared targets into one string, then bind that along with the higher ratings created above:

```
cc <- lapply(combos, paste, collapse='_')
final<- lapply(1:NROW(higher_rating), 
               function(i) {
                  x <- cbind(higher_rating[[i]], cc[[i]]); 
                  rownames(x) <- raters; 
                  x
               })

head(final, 1)
[[1]]
        [,1]      [,2]             
rater1  "target2" "target1_target2"
rater2  "target1" "target1_target2"
rater3  "target2" "target1_target2"
rater4  "target2" "target1_target2" ...
```

I'm sure there are less clumsy ways to do this.